# How to handle a heavy traffic on EC2 API Server after pushing a notification to mobile app?

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server

My company is running food market apps and every 11:00AM, we push an app notification using AWS SNS service. Recently, we are having a heavy traffic and our 5 API servers on EC2(t2.medium) become very unstable. The problem is that heavy traffic only comes about 10 mins right after we send a push notification(11:00AM to 11:10AM). So I applied an auto-scaling but did not work because launching servers took some time and it crashes before scaling up. We are a start-up company so minimizing costs on servers would be wonderful. What solutions can be worked in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend a number areas to review:

1. EC2 Instance Size. Look at enabling T2 Unlimited. This was just announced at re:Invent 2017. This feature removes the CPU throttling that occurs. You only pay if you use it.
2. Auto Scaling. Before your push notification, increase your Auto Scaling Group manually, then reduce it after the blitz.
3. If your EC2 instances are taking a long time to come online, consider creating your own AMI with the instances already configured to reduce the time to come online.
4. Load Balancers. Amazon Classic Load Balancers require pre-warming before big spikes in traffic. If you are using CLB, upgrade to the newer ALB or NLB.
5. SSL Termination. Terminate your SSL at the load balancer. This will reduce CPU load on the EC2 instances.
6. CloudFront / S3. Move your static assets (img, js, css, graphics, documents, flyers, etc.) to S3 and serve via CloudFront.
7. Put CloudFront in front of your load balancers.
8. Reduce the speed of your push notification.

Comment: All great suggestions; @hodoo-lee; if you want anything more specific - you'll need to give more information on your setup.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I will try what I can do.